# How to insert multi rows by stored procedure with array parameter

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

For example i have an array data like this:

```
Array(
   Array('name' => 'name 1', 'key' => 'abc1', 'expired' => '12/12/2017'),
   Array('name' => 'name 2', 'key' => 'abc2', 'expired' => '12/11/2017')
)
```

I can use foreach in source code to call stored procedure to insert each row, but is it possible to pass an array data to stored procedure and use WHILE loop to insert all data?

I'm using phpMyAdmin 4.6.5.2

Thanks

Comment: The information you provided is not enough. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and for more information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Try constructing a single query with all the data you want to insert instead. Something like `INSERT INTO table_name (name, key) VALUES ("name 1", "abc1"), ("name 2", "abc2"); Stored procedures are typically used for updating related data in the database, they're a good way to shoot yourself in the foot as a noob :).  If you aren't writing mysql queries directly try asking a different question about your database framework or ORM

Comment: There is no array data type in mysql. In recent versions you may try using json, but pls note, it may be more efficient to implement the loop in the php code.

Comment: Ok i got it, thanks for your help guys!